# Display extra information in FullCalendar day tile

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

In [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) used in Angular web app, how can extra information with custom CSS be displayed at the bottom of day tile as seen (i.e. 16 CALLS SALE 8 in blue color text) in the screen capture below?

[image]

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/day-cell-render-hooks